# How do I stop Python's Sys module's "stdout" and "stderr" write method from returning the numbers of characters written

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, sys

whenever I use the `write` method from the `stdout` or `stderr` object in Python's built-in "`sys`" module in Python with the Python interpreter, the method also prints an integer representing the number of characters there are in the string after the string that I provided as an argument for the `text` parameter for the `stdout` or `stderr` method, which is really frustating as I only want the text, not also the string length.
For example:

```
>>> sys.stdout.write('string')
string6
```

I only wanted to print "`'string'`", not the string length (`6`) as well.
I have tried to solve this problem by using `sys.stdout.write('string')[:-1]` which I think would also remove the number of characters that is placed after the string

I then found out that the number of characters in the string that I provided as an argument is appearing because I was using the interpreter, and the interpreter prints values that are returned by functions but not printed.

So what I want to do is to call `sys.stdout.write('test')` but stop it from returning the number of characters in the string that I provided as the `text` argument. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.stdout.write` also prints the integer after the string that was provided as an argument for the `text` parameter in the method call because the `write` method of the `stdout` object also returns the length of the `text` parameter's argument, and the Python REPL/Interpreter also prints out returned values, which is the answer for your problem.

So, to stop it from printing out the length of the `text` string, just assign the `sys.stdout.write` method call to a variable, as it will call the function and then you can `del` the variable after it executes, as you will not want the returned number of characters in the string that was provided for the `text` parameter.

Another solution to this problem is by calling the `sdtout` object's `write` method in a function and then calling that function like:

```
def show_text(txt):
    from sys import stdout
    stdout.write(txt)
    return
show_text('Hello!)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *stop* a ready-made function from doing what it does when you call it. What you can do is stop the Python interpreter from printing the returned value by doing something with it, e. g. assigning it to a variable.